# trying to add text file elements to an array list

Tags: java

I"m currently trying to read text from a text file (of course) and then trying to add them to my arraylist but it's not working when i try to use the add method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
public class Inventory
{
private String store;
private ArrayList<Flooring> products = new ArrayList();
public Inventory(String args[], ArrayList<Flooring> products) throws IOException{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("Lowes.txt");
    BufferedReader text = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = text.readLine();

    while(line != null){
        products.add(line);
        line = text.readLine();
    }

    FileReader reader1 = new FileReader("Sam's Club Flooring.txt");
    BufferedReader text1 = new BufferedReader(reader1);

    FileReader reader2 = new FileReader("Home Depot.txt");
    BufferedReader text2 = new BufferedReader(reader2);
}

}
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "not working".

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: What is `Flooring`. Do you really need to import `import java.lang.Object.*;`

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method is not working because the `ArrayList` contains objects of type `Flooring`. So **it will only accept `Flooring` objects** and not `String`.

```
private ArrayList<Flooring> products = new ArrayList();
```

SOLUTIONS:

- Change type to `ArrayList<String>`
- Fill some `String` attribute of a `Flooring` object and add it to list

Comment: So pretty much i can create a "Flooring = text.readLine();" and it would read the flooring as the string in the text file?

Comment: what? `Flooring = text.readLine()` is not valid, but you can use `String s = text.readLine()` as I explain in answer

Comment: Also, what is `Flooring` object? Post the class code in the question

Comment: Well the Array List is supposed to hold Strings of text from the file and the Text is types of Wood flooring, so i figured that the object type would be flooring, but it would never compile so i changed it to being String... and also I am not very good with using stackoverflow so i have no clue on how to do something on this feed... sorry..

Comment: nono, text types does not mind here, just use `ArrayList<String>` instead of `ArrayList<Flooring>`

Comment: ohhh, okay okay. I got that. So now i have it added and it works fine. Now for me to ask further questions do i have to create a whole new post?

Comment: yes, chameleon (changing) questions are not allowed in StackOverflow. You can mark the answer that solved this question to get and give rep, and write a new question, of course, in the new one, you can link this question if necessary to save words :)

Answer (score 0):

your `ArrayList` is defined to only hold variables of the type `Flooring`, hence you can´t add `String` values to it.

You might want to change the List definition to `List<String>`.

Or you want to to create new instances of `Flooring` depending on the line.

```
products.add(new Flooring(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

products is an `ArrayList` of `Flooring` objects, you are trying to add `line` to it. `line` is a `String`.

If you want to add `line`, you want to initialize your `products` List like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add String object to a non String arraylist.

```
private ArrayList<Flooring> products = new ArrayList();
```

This line clearly defines that ArrayList products will accept only objects of class Flooring.

Answer (score 0):

The add method is not working because the ArrayList contains objects of type Flooring. So it will only accept Flooring objects and not String.

private ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
SOLUTIONS:

Change type to ArrayList
Fill some String attribute of a Flooring object and add it to lis